# What else do Margaery and Loras have in common according to Cersei?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I came upon this interesting thought of Cersei's in *A Feast for crows* in the second Cersei chapter

> (during Tywin's Funeral)

Cersei looks at Margaery and thinks:

> Queen Margaery, she reminded herself; Joff’s widow and Tommen’s wife-to-be. Margaery looked very like her brother, the Knight of Flowers. **The queen wondered if they had other things in common**.
>
> *-A Song of Ice and Fire: A Feast for Crows, Cersei.*

I am specifically interested in the line where Cersei wonders if they have more in common:

**Does she mean what Margaery and Loras have in common with each-other, or Margaery and Loras have in common with Cersei and Jaime?**

Is Cersei wondering if Margaery and Loras are

> also sleeping with each-other as Cersei and Jaime are?

Or is she wondering whether there are things about Margaery (character wise or in looks) which Loras shares?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the "worst kept secrets" in the Tyrell family is the fact that Loras is actually homosexual. Given that Margaery had, at one point, been married to Renly, who was also well-known to be "secretly" homosexual, it seems most likely that Cersei is implying that Margaery may actually be a lesbian.

It's not clear if Cersei is just being mean within her own mind, if she actually believes this might be true, or if she's merely looking for something she may use against Margaery in the future. Being "outed" as homosexual would most likely invalidate her marriage to Tommen, as she would presumably have never wanted to consummate it. This is exactly the kind of rumor that Cersei might keep in her back pocket in case she needed it.

Answer (score 17):

Like explained [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/57043/24826) it is well known that Loras is homosexual. But there are no hints in the books that Margaery is so too.

In my interpretation Cersei is asking herself what Margaery and Loras have in common and specificly if they have have both slept with the same men (for example Renly who was known to have a relationship with Loras and was married to Margaery, if only for a few days).

Comment: Interestingly I watched a S3 episode last night where Joffrey was talking to Margaery and mentioned making the "depravity" punishable by death. I didn't get any indication she was worried about herself over her brother. Obviously this is an actresses' interpretation though.

Comment: This didn't occur to me until you mentioned it, because I don't think it's really hinted at in the books; but there is a scene in the show after Margaery and Renly's wedding where she brings Loras into the bedroom with her, so this also makes sense.

Comment: Can you add examples of the "hints that Margaery is (also homosexual)"?

Comment: "But there are **no** hints ..."